# Query matched 0 results, verify your query

Tags: r

I'm trying to develop an dashboard in Excel, using R studio.

I have now the code:

```
session01 <- Init(start.date = '2015-02-01', 
               end.date = '2015-04-01', 
               dimensions = 'ga:date,ga:userType',
               metrics = 'ga:sessions',
               sort = 'ga:date',
               segments = NULL,
               max.results = 10000, 
               start.index = NULL, 
               table.id = 'ga:XXXXXXX')


session01 <- QueryBuilder(session01)
report02 <- GetReportData(session01, oauth_token_LO)
```

However, it get this message:

```
> report02 <- GetReportData(session01, oauth_token_LO)
Your query matched 0 results. Please verify your query using the Query Feed Explorer and re-run it.
Error in GetDataFeed(query.uri) : 
  no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?